# Minimize a equation using opencv

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, minimize, minimization

I need to solve the following equation:

[image]

I Know the matrix `G`, how can I find the the matrix `p` subject to `||p|| = 1`.

Currently I am solving in opencv as follows:

```
Mat  w, u, EigenVectors;
SVD::compute(A, w, u, EigenVectors);
Mat p = EigenVectors.row(EigenVectors.rows-1);
```

I want to know how can I ensure the condition ||p|| = 1.
Also I want to know the `significance and meaning of other rows/cols` of the `EigenVectors`(transposed) ?

Comment: The other eigenvectors correspond to larger eigenvalues, so they don't minimize your objective function.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use [cv::SVD::solveZ()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#svd-solvez). It finds a unit-length solution **x** of a singular linear system **A** * **x** = **0**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use [Lagrange multipliers method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

As I know, OpenCV have no ready to use tools for that.

Good example for MATLAB: [Lagrange Multipliers](http://matlab.cheme.cmu.edu/2011/12/24/using-lagrange-multipliers-in-optimization/)